Async import with dynamic path react-native
In web I can use async import with dynamic path. In react-native there is error
export function App() {
  const load = async (path: string) => {
    // I have success - {"test": [Function test]}
    const res = await import('./theme/test');

    // I have error - Invalid call at line 30: import(`./theme/${path}`)]
    const res2 = await import(`./theme/${path}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    load('test');
  }, []);

  return <Text>test</Text>;
}

How I can use async import with dynamic path in react-native? Maybe need special settings on metro.config.js
in MDN described simmilar case 

export function App() {
  const moduleMap = {
    test: require('./theme/test'),
    // Add more mappings as needed
  };

  const load = async (path: string) => {
    const modulePath = moduleMap[path];
    if (!modulePath) {
      // Handle case when path is not found in moduleMap
      return;
    }
    const res = await modulePath;
    console.log(res);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    load('test');
  }, []);

  return <Text>test</Text>;
}

Hi Shperung. please try this code and use require instead of import.

Yes, this way works fine. However I necessary reuse code from the web react application (on the web "react+webpack" works correctly). I need right way to use async import with dynamic path. if it is possible.
